# Minify javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick, swap

HTML:

```
<div class="product-view">
<img id="myimg" src="img/grayimg.jpg" width="372" height="511">
</div>
<ul>
<li><img class="colorbox" style="background-color:gray;" onclick="changecolor1()" alt></li>
<li><img class="colorbox" style="background-color:green;" onclick="changecolor2()" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function changecolor1() {
        document.getElementById("myimg").src = "img/grayimg.jpg";
    }
</script>
<script>
    function changecolor2() {
        document.getElementById("myimg").src = "img/greenimg.jpg";
    }
</script>
```

In this example I maked a Image color swap for my product image. This example is working fine, but want somehow to minify the js code and not to write the script for every color or other options available.

It is possible somehow?

I saw on other sites that they are implementing the color swap method like this

`onclick="changeImage('WIN0128GRN', '4219', '8656', 'Chalkboard Charm - Green', '2561')"`

Can I make something similar to my example, to include attributes like in the example above?

I'm completely new to javascript and jquery, so I will be very grateful for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom `data-*` attributes in your HTML, specify the color, create the source from that color and apply:

```
<img class="colorbox" data-color="green" style="background-color:gray;" onclick="changeColor(this)" />

function changeColor(elem) {
    var color = elem.getAttribute("data-color");
    var newImageSrc = "img/" + color + "img.jpg";
    document.getElementById("myimg").src = newImageSrc;
}
```

Comment: I might push to also have the target element (in this case `#myimg`) be a separate data-attribute as well, in case there are multiple `.product-view` elements on the page.

Comment: but If I want to swap for example the shape of the product, not the color, what should I use instead of "data-color" type?

Comment: @andryesh -- Anything you want that helps you denote the shape of the clicked element... `data-shape`?

Comment: @tymeJV - ohh sorry for that, now it's all clear, thx for support.

Comment: @Cory - In my case there will be one `.product-view` element per page.

Comment: @tymeJV - your example is working flawlessly, thank you very much.

Comment: @tymeJV - but how to implement this function if I have on my product page 2 options > 1.color 2.shape?

Will need a totally different function to call,yes?